# PHP pg_prepare() table name as parameter

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to convert this query from a normal `pg_query()` to `pg_prepare() & pg_execute()`. Its a generic query that I reuse when I need to update different tables from different pages in order to keep my code clean.

I've just realised that parameters can be used only in `where` clauses and not in other parts of the query.

```
$res = pg_query($con, "update " .  $_REQUEST['table'] . " set " . $_REQUEST['colname'] . "=" . $colval . " where " . $_REQUEST['colnameid'] . "=" . $_REQUEST['colvalid'] . " returning " . $_REQUEST['colnameid'] );
```

**Tried this code:**

```
$res = pg_prepare($con, "upd", "update $1 set $2=$3 where $4=$5 returning $6");

$res = pg_execute($con, "upd", array($_REQUEST['table'],$_REQUEST['colname'],$colval,$_REQUEST['colnameid'],$_REQUEST['colvalid'],$_REQUEST['colnameid'] ));
```

This is failing. Is there any way to achieve this or a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Bind parameters are a mechanism to isolate data from code. You want to generate code dynamically, which is an entirely different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot bind identifiers, only values.

Identifiers (table names, field names, etc.) are not supposed to be user inputs in the first place. It is a very bad idea to handle them in such a way.